# How to show a map within a node using gmap and location modules

Tags: 7, location, google-maps

I'm trying to save a location together with the node of a certain content type and when the node is shown I want the location to show up on a map within the node content. I use the Gmap and Location Modules, and I manage to save locations to the database, but the map doesn't show up. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the display settings of your content type, you should be able to change the value to "Map only" or "Adress with Map".

Then it should display it as a GMap.

I use:

- GMAP
- GMAP Location
- Node Locations
- Location CCK

I think you're missing Location CCK, in order to get the Map stored as a field in the content type.

Otherwise, if you use the content Location, I think the map is available as a block (not sure about this one).

Comment: I have done exactly this and use the modules you mention. The field type is set to Location and the widget is set to Location Field and the display settings are set to map only. I also have a field named "Location" that is added to the content type automatically, and if I fill in this field, I get a LINK to a map displaying the correct position. This is really confusing. Could anyone please explain how this works?

Comment: One common mistake is that you can enable Location from the content type (/admin/structure/types/manage/[MY_CONTENT_TYPE]) and also as a field (/admin/structure/types/manage/[MY_CONTENT_TYPE]/fields). You should not enable both. It's easier IMO to use the CCK field. Could you please provide some screenshot of your content type, Location field and display configuration? Thank you.

Comment: THANK YOU! I had both enabled and this was causing the problem!